# I am trying to create-react app but I get this output:-

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-20.04

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts` with cra-template...

```
npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/cra-template failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 10.240.72.35:8080

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/natanan/.npm/_logs/2021-11-13T06_25_16_865Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a stable network connection, then run the **create-react-app** again or try using yarn instead of npm

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
  $ ping registry.npmjs.org
    $ npm view npm version
```

If the ping is not successful, there are multiple options:

1. check your connection
2. check your firewall
3. check your proxy

For me, it was the proxy and I had to disable the option Detect automatically the settings

Comment: npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno EHOSTUNREACH
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 10.240.72.35:8080

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/natanan/.npm/_logs/2021-11-14T11_59_27_164Z-debug.log

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: I edited my answer can you check it and share the result then someone can help you

Comment: go to setting > proxy setting on your computer. Search for network and internet

Answer (score 0):

solved!
$sudo npm install -g create-react-app
$sudo create-react-app my-app